# same layout for some pages in Yii2

Tags: php, layout, yii

I am a newbie at yii . I have a page called main.php . I want some of the other pages to use main.php as layout. my project views are in "site" folder. I create a folder for that views and a separated controller. but it doesn't work.I add   $this->layout = 'main' to my project

Comment: update your question  .. add the code for an controllerAction sample

Answer (score 1):

Put your `main.php` or any layout files in `views/layouts` folder.

Use this in controllers: `public $layout = '/main';`

Or in actions:  `$this->layout = '/main';`

Answer (score 0):

In your Yii2 scaffolding should be there a directory

your_application/views/layouts

put the layout file main.php  in this dir

(or edit or replace the existing one)

once you have done  in the controllerAction where you need the new layout  assign the layout

```
$this->layout = 'main';
```

.

```
class YourController extends Controller
{
    ....
    public function actionYourAction()
    {
        .......

        $this->layout = 'main';
        return $this->render( ....        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing for **ALL** controllers and actions you must add this in your `config/main.php` file:

```
[
     // ...
     'layout' => 'main',
     'components' => [
         //...
     ]
]
```

Change in one controller:

```
class SiteController extends Controller

{

    public $layout='//layouts/main';

    public function init() {
        // ...
    }
    //...
}
```

Change just in one action:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $this->layout = 'mian';

    return $this->render('index', ['model' =>$model]);
}
```